# How to save data to instance variable of an object which is put through Model to HTML file using Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, object, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I'm making a simple java web app using spring boot and thymeleaf, it's about calculating the total amount of food's calories you eat. I completed the search food task. In selecting food task, in HTML file, i have object named user and food, however, i can not save the food's calories quantity which user click on it - actually i want to add the food calories just clicked to user.sumcalo 
Can you give me some suggestions?

// This is a part of HTML code to show the database of searched food :
[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPiE8.png)

// This is a part of the script in above HTML file:
[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znxJZ.png)

```
 <script  th:inline="javascript" >
      /*<![CDATA[*/
      function addCalo(x) {
          var calo = [[${user.getSumcalo()}]] + parseInt(x) ;
          document.getElementById("showCalo").innerText = "Calo = 
  "+ calo ;
           [[${user.setSumcalo(calo)}]]; // -> This line has no 
   effect, i want to set user.sumcalo to calo
       }
     /*]]>*/
 </script>
```

expected [[${user.setSumcalo(calo)}]] worked but it did not.

Comment: this is the web's UI: https://imgur.com/a/7QBoDSd

Comment: I could not understand what you are actually trying to do. Could you please try to explain

Comment: Okay.  I created a maven project , i used java spring boot + thymeleaf . In controller , i created a method like this: https://imgur.com/a/4dFYVkH . This is User class code: https://imgur.com/a/dbEH95b .  In the correspond HTML file (CaloriesLack.html), I want whenever clicking a button X, user.sumcalo will be added 10 (for example) -> how can i do it? Can i do it by using javascript  Can you give me some suggestions?

Comment: Oh, silly me, just save the object in Controller class - Problem solved.